# Using Euler theorem show that $a^{\frac{\varphi(m)}{2}}\equiv \pm1 \pmod m,~where~(a,m)=1$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Euler Theorem**:  $a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv 1 \pmod m ,$ For $(a,m)=1.$

Using the above show that for $m=p^\alpha$ where $p$ is prime and $m\geq3$
$$a^{\frac{\varphi(m)}{2}}\equiv \pm1 \pmod m,~where~(a,m)=1$$
I know $\varphi(m)$ is even. So $\frac{\varphi(m)}{2}$ is some integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you get if you square $a^{\phi(m)/2}$?

Comment: The square is $a^{\phi(m)}$

Comment: Right.  Can you simplify that?  Then, what are its square roots?

Comment: What do you mean "its square root"?

Comment: First, what is $a^{\phi(m)}$ equal to?

Comment: I think you are saying that since $$ a^{\varphi(m)}\equiv1(mod~m)$$     then the square root of $ a^{\varphi(m)}$  is $\equiv\pm1(mod~m)$?

Comment: Yes, $x^2\equiv1\pmod m$, so $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$ is a multiple of $m$.  The only factor that $x-1$ and $x+1$ have in common is $2$, so Hmm, I didn't consider $p=2$.  But apart from that, one of $x+1$ or $x-1$ contains all the powers of $p$.

Comment: That was Splendid!